# Why my C++ program can only read absolute directory but not file in the same file folder?

Tags: c++, io, ifstream, absolute-path

I wrote a small VC++ program using VS2012 and tried to read an text file. I put the file in the release folder. However I cannot read the file until using the absolute file directory. I cannot find useful information online though. The code is like this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl;
    string test;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("E:\\Glus\\Project2\\Release\\bunny.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        string s0,s1;
        int x0, x1;
        myfile>>s0>>x0;
        cout<<s0<<x0<<endl;
        myfile>>s1>>x1;
        cout<<s1<<x1<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Error in reading file!"<<endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
    cin>>test;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the directory you have told VS to start your program in? That's not necessarily the same directory where the `.exe` file lives.

Comment: By default VS uses the project folder as the current directory whereas the executables are built to `..\Win32\Release` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The path is not relative to the executable, but to the current directory (see [`_getcwd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx)).

In case you are launching the application from VC, try

```
"..\\Release\\bunny.txt"
```

For a real life application, I'd suggest to detect the path of the executable and use it to construct the path to the data file. It is more reliable and safer.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio does not save your program exactly where you run it, actually it saves it in your a folder within your project folder with same name of your project
you can get current working path using this command :

```
system("cd");
```

it can solve your problem to locate your files.

Comment: It just output the current directory if I added it before reading the file but without changing to the current release folder though